# How to move Cursor in Java Jsoup while loop?

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using Jsoup with while loop but the cursor stuck at a=0. I have tried to move it by added `doc.next();` but not working. I want a run from 0-29 in the url. Thank you!
Edited: The url structure is www.example.com/0, www.example.com/1,www.examplecom/2,www.example.com/3,www.example.com/4.....to unlimited "a", but only one number contain the information i need ( range from 0-30). There is no 404 return. The problem is the cursor does not move to the next "a", it's stuck at a=0. There must be someway to make the cursor move because the loop don't move it.

```
try {
    int a = 0;
    boolean condition = true;
    while (a < 30 && condition) {

        doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.example.com/" + a).get();

        Elements info = doc.select("td[valign=top]");
        if (null != info) {
            System.out.println(info);
            condition = false;
            System.out.println(a);
        } else {
            a = a + 1;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what URL you want to create? Currently your code would create the URLs `www.google.com0` till `www.google.com29`.

Comment: I have update the URL information. Yes, i want to create url like: www.example.com/0,www.example.com/1,www.example.com/2,www.example.com/3,www.example.com/4...www.example.com/30. And one of these URL have the data i'm looking for. But the code just create www.example.com/0 and the cursor stuck and that, i want it move forward to check the rest 1-30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve here, but I will tell you why the loop is stuck at 0.

It is because the url you are trying to access with Jsoup (e.g. www.google.com0) **is not a valid url**, and it will return a `404` response, which Jsoup will treat as a `http exception`, and hence the loop is stopped and the control goes to `catch` block to catch the exception.

If you really want to go from 0 to 29, below code will work for you:

---

**UPDATE:**

I now see the problem. Change your code to this:

```
try {
    int a = 0;
    boolean condition = true;
    while (a < 30 && condition) {

        try{
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com" + a).get();
        } catch(Exception jsoupE){
            continue;
        }

        Elements info = doc.select("td[valign=top]");
        if (info.first() != null) {
            System.out.println(info);
            condition = false;
            System.out.println(a);
        } else {
        a = a + 1;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i have update the information about the url. There is no error here, no 404 url not valid. it's run but the cursor stuck at a=0 and i don't know how to make it move forward. Thank you!

Comment: It seems like you are stopping the loop if "info" is not null. Right?

Comment: Do you want the loop to stop when info is NOT found? It stopped at a=0 because info was not found (info is null). That seemed to be a intended output.

Comment: No i want it stopped when the info is not null ( when i found the info) "null != info" condition= false and the while loop stop. If not found, a=a+1

Comment: So i think i got the same problem like this one, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664078/java-jdbc-result-set-error-but-why. It's because the cursor not move forward with the loop but i don't know how to solve this. Thank you!

Comment: Please see my updated answer

Comment: It's work, you are genius, thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to be of help :) good luck!